# Security risk of storing passwords as hex compared to binary

Tags: binary, hex, password-encryption

I've just been working through a tutorial which told me to use the hash_hmac to hash my passwords, with the setting 'true' to output in binary format. Then save this as a varbinary(32) format in my MySql database.

I've spent the last hour working on the user login form and I've been having difficulty comparing the hashed passwords from the input, and the hashed password from the database as I think I've been getting confused with differences in hex/binary somewhere.

My question is: what are the benefits of storing passwords in binary format? Is it merely a space saving measure? Or does it improve security some way?

If it's just a space saving measure I think I'll store them as hex, because to me it's easier to work with.

Thanks

Comment: It saves space, but it's also the native format. Hex is merely a text representation of the byte data. It's trivial to convert from one to the other in most languages, so why take up more space than you need by storing it as text?

Comment: BTW, your proposed solution: "If it's just a space saving measure I think I'll store them as hex, because to me it's easier to work with," is the lazy programmer's way out. A good programmer asks, "why is my implementation of the RIGHT way not working?" And proceed to learn how to do it the right way. It's just as easy (often times easier) to compare bytes than characters. It's also less prone to error as character sets and character casing don't come into play.

Comment: But that's the very problem. When storing with Varbinary, I'm getting a load of question marks in black triangles. It's not clear what these are and how to compare them. With hex, I can clearly see if two hashed passwords will match.

Comment: My point is, the question you SHOULD be asking (and separate from this) would involve you posting the code in question and asking for help in getting it working the right way instead of pursuing a bad programming practice simply because it's simpler.

Comment: When you say "Hex is the native format" are you referring specifically to the output of hash_hmac? Otherwise, from how I interpret what you're saying, are you suggesting everything in a database should be stored as binary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it merely a space saving measure? Or does it improve security some
>   way?

It is certainly a space-saving measure to store it as binary in a `varbinary(32)` instead of text in a `char()`. Storing it one way or the other won't impact security.